# 503- Request Timeout from Spring Boot application

Tags: java

I have an endpoint in the Spring boot application which is deployed in the AWS(ECS) and that endpoint processes file upload. When I am hitting uploading file using this endpoint it gives me 503 in 30s. While service runs and completes the upload.

How to fix this 503 issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is my rest service is giving me Request time out while my service is able to complete the task in backend.

Comment: Can you show your controller/service please ?

Comment: It is a kind of sample rest controller and the service has ThreadPoolExecutor. and in the tasks, it calls some third-party service.

Comment: Due to the Company policy, I can't write code here.

Comment: In Service we have code like the below:

Comment: ExectorService ecs= new ThreadPoolExcecutor()

Comment: int nt= Runtime.getRuntime().availableprocessors();
ExectorService ecs= new ThreadPoolExcecutor(nt, 20, 0, TimeUnit.Seconds, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2000), new ThreadPoolExecutor().AbortPolicy());
List<Future<String>> list=ecs.invokeAll(tasks());

return list.stream().filter(Future::isDone).map(future-> future.get()).collect(Collectors.toList());